# I' m facing issue while create cookie using cross-domain(python flask, ReactJS)

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, cookies

This problem is related to python3.5 and react16.2. When I was trying to set a cookie from cross-domain using python flask as a backend and react as a frontend. In this scenario, I can't able to set a cookie in the browser. So Is there any security in react that does not allow to set a cookie in the browser...

I set a cookie using set_cookie() method of flask.

Scenario: 
When I tried to set a cookie from iframe at that time I can't able to set a cookie in the browser. and I didn't get any error in python.

```
res = Response(json.dumps(schema.dump(self.message).data), mimetype="application/json")
res.set_cookie(key, value, expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=40))
```

I think this issue related ReactJS. Is there any property that violates cross domain concept.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using set_cookie on a response object as in this example:

```
@app.route('/setcookie', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def setcookie():
   if request.method == 'POST':
   user = request.form['nm']

   resp = make_response(render_template('readcookie.html'))
   resp.set_cookie('userID', user)

   return resp
```

If you are post a sample of the code and I will see if I can help.

Comment: thank u for your response. But when I tried to set cookie from cross domain at that time I can't able to set cookie. Do you know any properties that restrict to set cookie in browser in ReactJS.

Comment: In your question you mention trying to set a cookie from an iframe. Is that iframe on the same domain as your site? it isn't possible to set a cookie for one domain on another.

Comment: yes, I want to set a cookie from an iframe. No, It's a different domain. It working on simple javascript, but I wonder why it's not working with ReactJS

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the issue. I doubt that the problem is caused by React. How are you setting the cookie in an iframe using flask? Flask runs on the server. Not the front end. Might be able to help more if you are able to show me the whole file or ideally the repository your code is in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. when you are trying to set cookies from python to ReactJS using cross-domain then you have to include one property in ReactJS which is

```
withCredentials: False
```

This property allows you to set a cookie.